# Deny all network communication iOS within app

Tags: ios, swift, wifi

Is there any way to deny all network communication in iOS App based on a condition? E.g. If the device is in a particular location, it should turn down all network communication within the app. (Not the device). So basically app can be launched but have no outside communication. I searched around but could not find a suitable solution.

Comment: It's your app. You have code to perform networking operations. Don't call that code under whatever conditions you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you will stop your requests/webviews with specific statement in application. You can create a bool variable, that will be checking before all the requests or webviews and change its value according to situation. Or you can write a func, that will contain code for break all of you requests and call it when you need it. Unfortunately, you can not break an internet connection for specific app, but if you can deny all the requests, isn't it the same? :)